# C++ Loop(triangle-drawer)

Tags: c++, geometry, drawing

i cant get my program to work, i tried it already with markers (goto).
but i cant get it to work. I also tried to improve the loop but it ends with an infinite loop. Thanks for Help!

```
#include <iostream> //includes
using namespace std;
int makedreieck(int länge) // function for drawing a triangle
{
    int rows=0; //rows
    int draw=0; //drawed
    while(draw <= länge)
    {
        draw++;
        cout << "*";
        if(draw == länge-1)
        {
            rows++;
            draw = länge-rows;
            cout << endl;
        }
        if(draw == 1)
        {
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(char argument)
{
    int dreieck;
    cin >> dreieck;
    makedreieck(dreieck);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

finally got all working... if anyone needs the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

int createtriangle(int length, bool custom, char symbol)
{
    clock_t start, finish;
    length++;
    int OK=0;
    int OK_ABORT;
    int TRIANGLE_NOT_ALLOWED;
    enum returnvalues{OK, OK_ABORT, TRIANGLE_NOT_ALLOWED};
    if(length<=0)
    {
        cerr << "Dreieck mit einer Laenge von " << length-1 <<" unerlaubt.";
        return TRIANGLE_NOT_ALLOWED;
    }
    if(length>81)
    {
        cout << "Es wurde eine ueber 80 Sternchen lange Treppe entdeckt." << endl << "Es wird empfohlen die Operation abzubrechen"<< endl << "1: abbrechen 2: weiter"<<endl<<"Auswahl: ";
        int sel;
        cin >> sel;
        getchar();
        if(sel>2)
        {
            cout << "Es gibt die Auswahl: "<<sel<<" nicht.";
        }
        system("cls");
        switch(sel)
        {
        case 1:
            return OK_ABORT;
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        }
    }
    int rows=0;
    int draw=0;
    start = clock();
    while(draw <= length)
    {
        draw++;
        if(rows>=1&&custom==false)
        {
        cout << "*";
        }
        if(rows>=1&&custom==true)
        {
            cout << symbol;
        }

    if(draw == length)
    {
        if(rows>=1)
        {
        cout << endl;
        }
        rows++;
        draw = length-rows;
    }
    if(rows == length)
    {
        finish=clock();
        if(custom==false)
        {
        cout << "Es wurde eine "<<length-1<<" Sternchen lange Treppe gebaut."<<endl;
        }
        else if(custom==true)
        {
            cout << "Es wurde eine "<<length-1<<" "<<symbol<<" lange Treppe gebaut."<<endl;  
        }
        cout << "Es wurden "<< static_cast<double>( finish - start ) /CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< " Sekunden gebraucht.";
        return OK;
    }
    }
    return OK;
}
int main()
{
START:
    system("cls");
    int dreieck;
    char time[9];
    cout << "Wie gross soll die Treppe sein?: "; 
    cin >> dreieck;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Soll ein custom symbol verwendet werden?"<<endl<<"Ja:1 Nein:2"<<endl<<"Auswahl: ";
    int menu2;
    cin >> menu2;
    system("cls");
    bool customtrue;
    char symbolcustom;
    if(menu2>2)
    {
        cout << "Die Auswahl: " << menu2 << " ist nicht verfügbar";
        getchar();
        goto START;
    }
    switch(menu2)
    {
    case 1:
        customtrue = true;
        cout << "Symbol angeben(1Char max): ";
        cin >> symbolcustom;
        break;
    case 2:
        customtrue = false;
        break;
    }
    system("cls");
    createtriangle(dreieck,customtrue,symbolcustom);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    menumark:
    system("cls");
    cout << "Soll erneut eine Treppe gebaut werden?"<<endl<<"1: Ja 2: Nein"<<endl<<"Auswahl: ";
    int menu;
    cin >> menu;
    if(menu>2)
    {
        cout <<"Es gibt keine "<<menu<<" Auswahl.";
        getchar();
            goto menumark;
    }
    switch(menu)
    {
    case 1:
        goto START;
        break;
    case 2:
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work. Did you debug?

Comment: Not much to go on here - what output do you expect and what output are you getting ?

Comment: You have one `return 0;` in `makedreieck`; you don't have one at the end.  The function should return `void` since you ignore its returned value, but you should _not_ ignore compiler warnings about functions not returning a value.  Compiler warnings should be fixed before posting code here.  (If your compiler is not warning, find out how to turn warnings on; if your compiler cannot be made to warn, get a better compiler.)  This has nothing to do with your problem.  What might is the `getchar()` in `makedreieck()`; that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Your first loop gets out by condition `(draw == 1)`. What do you want to do instead?

Comment: Step through it, by hand, and keep track of the values of the variables using pencil and paper. Much better way to learn than using a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Using your source code …

```
#include <iostream> //includes
using namespace std;
int makedreieck(int länge) // function for drawing a triangle
{
    int rows=0; //rows
    int draw=0; //drawed
    while(draw <= länge)
    {
        draw++;
        cout << "*";
        if(draw == länge-1)
        {
            rows++;
            draw = länge-rows;
            cout << endl;
        }
        if(draw == 1)
        {
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(char argument)
{
    int dreieck;
    cin >> dreieck;
    makedreieck(dreieck);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

the first few compilation errors with g++, …

```
[d:\dev\test]
> gnuc foo.cpp
foo.cpp:3:1: error: stray '\344' in program
foo.cpp:7:5: error: stray '\344' in program
foo.cpp:11:9: error: stray '\344' in program
foo.cpp:14:13: error: stray '\344' in program
foo.cpp:3:23: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'nge'
foo.cpp: In function 'int makedreieck(int)':
foo.cpp:7:21: error: expected ')' before 'nge'
foo.cpp:7:21: error: 'nge' was not declared in this scope
foo.cpp:7:24: error: expected ';' before ')' token
foo.cpp:5:9: warning: unused variable 'rows' [-Wunused-variable]
foo.cpp:32:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
foo.cpp:32:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

[d:\dev\test]
> _
```

are due to the MingW g++ compiler for Windows not conforming to the C++ standard about the character set accepted in identifiers. The particular character numbers reported are a bit odd because the source code was saved as Windows ANSI Western, but g++ errs out also with the source code as UTF-8. As of 2013 *few compilers are* conforming wrt. the source character set.

The only safe characters are A through Z, underscore, and the digits 0 through 9.

In practice this means: **write your source code in English**, the *lingua franca* of software development, and then it can be maintained by others and compiled by other compilers.

After fixing that I get the following compilation errors:

```
[d:\dev\test]
> gnuc foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int makedreieck(int)':
foo.cpp:19:21: error: 'getchar' was not declared in this scope
foo.cpp: At global scope:
foo.cpp:25:5: warning: first argument of 'int main(char)' should be 'int' [-Wmain]
foo.cpp:25:5: warning: 'int main(char)' takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
foo.cpp: In function 'int main(char)':
foo.cpp:30:13: error: 'getchar' was not declared in this scope
foo.cpp: In function 'int makedreieck(int)':
foo.cpp:23:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

[d:\dev\test]
> _
```

The errors here are due to not including the header `<stdio.h>` that declares the `getchar` function.

After fixing that there are no more errors reported.

However, the warnings are serious:

```
[d:\dev\test]
> gnuc foo.cpp
foo.cpp:27:5: warning: first argument of 'int main(char)' should be 'int' [-Wmain
foo.cpp:27:5: warning: 'int main(char)' takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
foo.cpp: In function 'int makedreieck(int)':
foo.cpp:25:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

[d:\dev\test]
> _
```

The non-standard `main` signature means that even after including the required header, this is *not valid C++*.

Just remove the (unused) formal argument.

Then the code compiles, with only one very serious warning remaining:

```
[d:\dev\test]
> gnuc foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int makedreieck(int)':
foo.cpp:25:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

[d:\dev\test]
> _
```

Which absolutely needs to be fixed!

Summing up:

- Change the code to not use non-English letters in identifiers. Those national characters are OK wrt. the C++ standard, but few compilers support them. In particular g++ does not.
- Include all required headers.
- Use a standard-conforming signature for `main`.

And remember to fix the missing `return` statement thing.

*Then* you can start debugging!

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration you set `draw` to 1, so `(draw == 1)` is true and the function returns.

Try decrementing `länge` instead of `draw` when `draw == länge-1`, reset `draw` to 0 at that point, and exit at the end of the loop when `länge == 1`. Adjust to taste.